# SIGKILL crash in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, ios4, sigkill

I had develop an iPad app. When i close the app by clicked the minus button on multitasking bar, i run the app again and iPad was crash and fully black screen.

After i connect with Xcode and found the error message is "SIGKILL" in main.m

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{    
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);        << Thread 1:Program received signal: "SIGKILL".

    [pool release];
    return retVal;
}
```

is there any solution for this error?

Answer (score 2):

Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5606158/ios-simulator-sigkill).

> Deleting the program from the multitasking bar stops it from running.
>   It's the equivalent of the "Force Quit" option you get in OS X when
>   right-clicking an application icon in the dock.
>
> At the iOS level, this is apparently done by sending the "kill"
>   signal, known as SIGKILL, to the application.